# Writing the result of a Javascript for-loop into a HTML 5 table

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am playing about with Javascript, and I've made a fictional hotel website that shows you hotel details when you click on a button.

http://jsfiddle.net/addiosamigo/4ev43b5m/8/

```
var hotel = {Name: "Park Hotel", Price: "£120.00", Rooms: 50}

  var hotel2 = {name: "West End", price: "£240.00", rooms: 150}

  el_p = document.getElementById("para1");
  el_picture = document.getElementById("picture");
  el_picture2 = document.getElementById("picture2");

  function showPrice() {

  el_picture2.style.display = "none";

  el_picture.style.display = "block";
  el_p.innerHTML = " ";
  for(details in hotel) {

  el_p.innerHTML += (details += ": " + hotel[details] + "<br />");

   }
  }

  function showPrice2() {

  el_picture.style.display = "none";

  el_picture2.style.display = "block";

  el_p.innerHTML = " ";
  for(details in hotel2) {

  el_p.innerHTML += ( details += ": " + hotel2[details] + "<br />");

    }


  }
```

first of all, is there an easier way to code this? I'm just learning so I just did what I could.

second of all how do I write the results of my for loop into a table?

thanks

Comment: This kind of question is better asked on `codereview.stackexchange.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use jQuery library (based on JS).

1) Create array of hotels:

```
var hotels = [
   {name: "Park Hotel", price: "£120.00", rooms: 50},
   {name: "West End", price: "£240.00", rooms: 150}
];
```

2) Create empty table:

```
<table id="hotelsTalbe">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Hotel name</th>
         <th>Price per room</th>
         <th>No. of rooms</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

3) Than just loop your `hotels`:

```
// Load jQuery first!
$.each(hotels, function(key, row){
    // this - current element in loop. $(this) - current jQuery element.
    $('#hotelsTable tbody').append(
        '<tr><td>'
        + row['name'] + '</td><td>'
        + row['price'] + '</td><td>'
        + row['rooms'] + '</td></tr>'
    );
});
```

In JS (not tested):

```
for (var i = 0; i < hotels.lenth; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var text = document.createTextNode(hotels[i]['name']);
    td.appendChild(textnode);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    document.querySelector("#hotelsTable tbody").appendChild(tr);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    text = document.createTextNode(hotels[i]['price']);
    td.appendChild(textnode);
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    text = document.createTextNode(hotels[i]['rooms']);
    td.appendChild(textnode);
    tr.appendChild(td);

    document.querySelector("#hotelsTable tbody").appendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: I really wanted to use javascript, but this is an excellent alternative thank you!

Comment: @Addioioi try using `appendChild()` in pure JS. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: This is sort of what I thought it would look like, although its only printing the table names, not the data. I'll see if I can fix it! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a javascript version using an HTML template and pure javascript instead of jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/dr6n88bu/15/

```
<script type="text/template" id="hotelTemplate">
    <img src="{img}" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name: </td>
            <td>{name}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price: </td>
            <td>{price}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rooms: </td>
            <td>{rooms}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent! just what I wanted, I don't understand it very well though so I will have to debug! thanks

Comment: One on the advantages to this method is that you aren't repeating your function. If you have any other questions after reviewing the fiddle let me know.

Comment: Ok, after looking at it I understand it fundamentally, (Well I think so, I mean I sort of see what it is doing). Could you just explain some of the code (or all of it) lol. in particular  var re = new RegExp('{' + prefix + p.toLowerCase() + '}', 'g'); I see that you are taking away the object indentifiers, so that the image shows, but I'm not sure what its doing after that. also what is this  var prefix = ((typeof arguments[1] === "string") ? arguments[1] + "." : ""); doing. finally, If I wanted to 'size' my images, how would I do this? thanks again

Comment: That function is just a way to replace the markers in the template like {img} using regular expressions which replaces the argument value which was passed. 
If you wanted to add a specific size in the structure you could add it to the data object, though a better route may be to set a max-width or max-height via css.